# Poltergeist incompatible with Rspec comparison matcher?

Tags: rspec, poltergeist

I have an assertion as follows:

```
expect(int_var).to be < 5
```

which works fine in selenium driver, but when I run it in poltergeist I get

```
undefined method '<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Does poltergeist really not support this? Is there a preferred better way to perform comparison matching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt this is due to Poltergeist. You have a `nil` value when your test expects an Integer. Try:

```
expect(nil).to be < 5
```

and you will see the same error.

Comment: You are correct. The int_var was getting a proper Integer when I ran the test in Selenium, thus the confusion. Thank you.